# What is the best practise for querying an big Spark result?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, bigdata

I'm trying to build an Recommendation Engine for an Onlineshop with ca. 50000 Articles. I created the frequently itemsets and rules with the FPGrowth an Apache Spark.

My first try was to put the Data (65G Rows) in a Database (PostgreSQL) as intarrays and with the gin Index the performance should be OK. But when Amount of rows is high the query need minutes. Low amounts needs ms.

What are the best practices for querying a big Spark result?

Comment: 65M rows is not that much. How does it translate into memory usage? It should be easy to handle in memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it looks like a homework assignment with no actual problem to be solved and also the description being unclear. What do you think @zero323 ?

Comment: @eliasah I guess you're right, but I'll try to drop back later and see if it improved.

Comment: Sry, typo, I mean 65G Rows or 4,7GB, this was a little german came through.This is the Size of CSV which is the Rusult of the FPGrowth. This is just a Test with a high support. The Itemsets and Itemrules

Comment: The Itemsets and Itemrules get more interesting with lower support, but when i can't handle this 4,7GB, how should i handle 100GB ? Is this the right way - throwing the Results in a database or am I totally wrong?